# Im trying to build a cryptocurrency(USD tether just like USD) that works with ethereum and polygon,

Tags: solidity, blockchain, tokens, smart-contract-wallets, binance

I happen to be relatively new to block chain, have an understanding of PoW and PoS, I'm learning Solidity at the moment, I'm supposed to design thi cryptocurrency that is compatible with ethereum and polygon. It has 45 days of subscription validity and then  expires thereafter .The smart contract is to be named as token and given an instruction of 45 days validity while buying
As this is the first block chain project that I'll be starting, can I get suggestions/ recommendations on how should I move ahead with the development. I'm asking people from community to help me with this!! :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to create a token with solidity is to inherit ERC20 contract and add whatever features you want.

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol